# Getting flexible horizontal scaling images to work in Safari

Tags: css, responsive-design, safari, image-scaling, responsive-images

Im working on a website where i have to crop images on the left and right side, and center them. I found a solution for this, with this code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dXMrWj

```
<div class='container'>
  <img src='https://source.unsplash.com/category/nature/800x1000/daily'>
</div>
```

-

```
body {
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Only it doesn't work in Safari, is presume because the "VH" unit maybe. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Should not be a `vh` problem: [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 1):

Adding  `object-fit: cover;` to the img styling seems to fix the problem in Safari and it still looks good in Chrome. Untested in other browsers

http://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/rLwAJd